# Finding distance travelled by differential drive robot

Tags: homework, robotics, mobile-robot

In a two wheeled differential drive robot, with wheel radius 7cm. bot starts from rest and the two motors are randomly actuated. Left wheel has rotated by 270 degrees, and the right wheel rotates by 320 degrees both in the clockwise direction. Find the distance travelled by the centre of the bot?
I am new to robotics, please help me the way such questions are tackled. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the picture below:

[image: solution]

In full rotation (360 degrees), the wheel will move a distance equal to the circumference i.e. 2*pi*R. For partial rotation, you can use unitary method (divide by 360 degrees, multiply by rotation angle).

The distance between the wheels doesn't matter in this case.

Distance traveled by the center of the robot will be the average of the distance traveled by both wheels.

Answer (score 1):

Draw out a path for each wheel as the robot turns continuously. You will draw two concentric circles whose difference in radius is the wheel spacing. Stare at it for long enough and you will eventually realize the path traveled is the circumference of a circle that sits in the middle of the circumference of the two other circles tracing out the wheel path. In other words, a circle whose radius is the average of the circles traced out by the wheels.

[image]

Therefore, the distance traveled is the average of the distance traveled by each wheel.

You can also figure out the angle that it has turned by in a similar way. If you know the distance traveled by each wheel you can figure out the radius of the two circles that maintain the wheel spacing. From there, you can average the radius of the two circles tracing out the wheel path to get the circle of movement of the body.

Since you know the distance traveled by the body, you can figure out how much arc it has traveled along the body circle and that lets you know the angle by which it has turned.

Comment: as advised, I stared at the picture for 1 minute but still have no idea. (1) Do I need to use my brain at the same time? (2) Is 1 minute long enough for me IQ 97? (3) what words do I need to search my friend Google, perhaps "differential drive", "distance", "wheel spacing", "wheel spacing"?

Comment: @tlfong01 Well, I guess you have to stare and trying to think about the relationship between the wheel path and movement of the body. It's not a magic picture, heh.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a well defined problem as you will end up in different locations depending upon the speed of the wheels.

I almost want to say you need to take a dynamic model into account because there will be wheel slip.

This is an example of a skid steer problem and cannot be modeled purely in terms of kinematics.

Comment: Yeah, in reality things get a lot messier due to slip and other errors and uncertainties. Having an idler wheels on each side that measure the distance traveled, separately from the driven wheels helps eliminate skid since only the driven wheels should skid errors since they are the ones applying force. Or you can get super fancy and have an optical mouse-type sensor on each side of the robot (just one if all you care is about distance traveled and not turn angle or radius.